# How to publish correctly on github?

Tags: git, web, github

I'm having problem publishing my web project on github even after I have set to master branch in settings that allows to be published, got a green tick, yet its shows 404.
[Image of my github repository or go to https://github.com/harnystiles/Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLgrQ.jpg)

The asset folder takes in all my css, js, font etc

Comment: I assume you're trying to use [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/)? Make sure you get the settings right? We can't really help you with the informs you have given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your Index.html to index.html and that should fix the problem.